# How to get WebRTC video to video streaming to decode video?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webrtc, peerjs

I have a working WebRTC connection between two people using [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com/docs.html#api) that captures a stream from a user video element and sends it to the other person. The video capture is as follows (working with React in Typescript):

```
useEffect(() => {

    const srcVideo = document.getElementById('normalVideo'); 
    const sinkVideo = document.getElementById('sinkVideo');
    
    if (srcVideo === null) return;

        const setSinkSrc = () => {
            let stream;
            const fps = 0; // Setting to zero means frames captured when requestFrame() is called.

            // @ts-ignore
            stream = srcVideo.captureStream(fps);
            // @ts-ignore
            sinkVideo.srcObject = stream;
            setStreamOut(stream);
        };

        srcVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', setSinkSrc);
        return () => {
            srcVideo.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', setSinkSrc);
        }
    }, [vidSrc]);
```

and sends it out with PeerJS:

```
mySocket.on('user-connected', (theirPeerID: string, theirSocketID: string) => {        
        if ( streamOut ) {            
            const outConnection: Peer.MediaConnection = myPeer.call(theirPeerID, streamOut);
            // This is weird. 
            // navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}).then(streamOut => myPeer.call(theirPeerID, streamOut));
        } 
    });
```

And the user connects with the stream

```
useEffect(() => {
        myPeer.on('call', (hostMediaConnection: Peer.MediaConnection) => {

            const sinkVideo = document.getElementById('sinkVideo');
            hostMediaConnection.answer();

            hostMediaConnection.on('stream', (hostStream: MediaStream) => {
                
                    console.log(hostStream.getAudioTracks().length);
                    console.log(hostStream.getVideoTracks().length);

                    if (sinkVideo === null || sinkVideo === undefined) {
                        console.log("Sink video either undefined or null");
                        return
                    } 
                    // Do not use URL.createObjectURL();
                    // @ts-ignore
                    sinkVideo.srcObject = hostStream;

                    // @ts-ignore
                    sinkVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
                        // @ts-ignore
                        sinkVideo.play();
                    });
            });

            hostMediaConnection.on("error", (err) => {
                console.log(err.type, "%cMediaConnectionError", "color:green;", err);
            });

        });
    }, []);
```

On a local stream, the video works just fine. Where the smaller element's data comes from a media stream: `sinkVideo.srcObject = stream;`

However, when this runs, there is just a black screen on the consumer side. Audio is streamed - and is able to be heard - but no video is ever shown. Going into chrome://webrtc-internals, I correctly see two RTCMediaConnections: outbound data from the source, and inbound data for the sink. Audio is being transmitted, video is being transmitted, video frames are being decoded, and yet nothing. The screen is black for the consumer, where it should not be.

So, my question is where am I going wrong? video is apparently being sent out, PeerJS makes a successful connection from the source to the sink, and the sink is decoding video. Audio has absolutely no problem at any point getting sent out or being recieved, decoded, and heard by the sink.

I have a comment above a line of commented out code.

```
// This is weird. 
// navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}).then(streamOut => myPeer.call(theirPeerID, streamOut));
```

Because when I send out my audio and video as the media, the stream is processed just fine, and the sink gets the video. This is one of the reasons I know that a successful WebRTC connection is being made: when I stream user webcam, data is sent.

[image: Where the bigger element is the local stream from the user, and the smaller element comes from the media stream]

Comment: captureStream from a video element might be bust currently, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1156408

Comment: I think you're totally right. Capture stream is already an experimental API (according to the MDN). I have hacked around it by creating blobs, then sending those blobs over a peer.DataConnection. It works, but there are some issues I need to address. For instance, it's not nearly as smooth as I would like. Thank you for the bug link, btw, it confirms that I shouldn't go insane about why my code ought to be working but isn't. For all future readers, this issue also occurs on Firefox: audio, but no video.